# Ember data 1.0.0: rollback after unsuccesfull save does not revert properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following behaviour with Ember Data 1.0.0 Beta 2:

Rollback of data changes (without first trying to save the changes):
- all data properties are restored to the previous version
- all flags in correct state

Rollback of data changes after an attempt to save, but the save returned a 422 error:
- none of the data properties are restored 
- isError flag remains true

I would expect that also in the second case the properties are set back to the previous state and that the isError flag is cleared.

This is how I revert:

```
cancel: function () {
      var author = this.get('model');
      author.rollback();
    },
```

Is this a known issue ?

thx

Comment: is this question still valid? Ember Data should rollback properties if the save fails, but the question and library version are so old that it probably doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: version too old. upgrade!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unanswered for several years, and asks about an extremely old version. It is unlikely to be answered in its current form. If you still need an answer for this under a newer version, please [edit] the question so that it may be reopened.